# IMPORTXML shows an error while scraping data from website

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to **scrape** List of **100 university** from this website [(topuniversity)](https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/usa-rankings/2021).

using `=IMPORTXML("https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/usa-rankings/2021","//*[@id='ranking-data-load']/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]")`

shows an error : `Imported content is empty.`

how to use xpath in order to fetch required data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this xhr requests in developer tools

> `https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/3738856.txt?1622189434?v=1622361479157`

and your xpath won't work unless rendering JavaScript

In order to do that you got 2 choices

- selenium / webbrowser (needs webdriver) either chrome or Firefox etc
- gather appropriate headers & data for sending request via Requests module

And the code

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/3738856.txt?1622189434?v=1622361479157'


headers = {
   "Host": "www.topuniversities.com",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux armv8l; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
   "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
   "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
   "Referer": "https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/usa-rankings/2021",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
   "via": "1.1 google"
}

datas = requests.get(URL, headers=headers).json()
import re

for i in datas['data']:
    for j in re.findall('class="uni-link">(.*)</a>',i['title']):
        print(j)
```

Results in

```
Harvard University
Stanford University
Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)
University of California, Berkeley (UCB)
University of California, Los Angeles (UCLA)
Yale University
```

Comment: @rene  can you please tell how did you find developer tool  and this url  : https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/3738856.txt?1622189434?v=1622361479157

Comment: @vish I didn't write the answer, I only edited it to make it a bit cleared. I have no idea what this user did to reach their answer.

Comment: @Sheshanandh can you please tell how did you find XHR request developer tool and this url